# How can I log each time Kubernetes kills a process due to resource use?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Is there any way to log this action / event?

It seems that if a process is using too much resources and is not the main process, it gets a SIGKILL signal. I'd like to log this action.

Comment: You want to know how to log this info or how to preserve it and check; once the pod is terminated?

Comment: the pod is never terminated

Answer (score 1):

You can use posthook to a run scripts when container is getting terminated.

Use that script to send notification or to log info to STDOUT.

Later when pod get killed, We can still get the older logs by using -p flag in kubectl logs.

Comment: It's not the container, it's the process within the container.

Comment: I believe a process in the container is making you cross resource limit and causing restart. You can use prehook and print processes usage stats in STDOUT to know which process is causing.

Comment: It's not restarting, it's the child process that gets terminated only.